# No overload for method 'SetValue' takes 7 arguments in Umbraco 9

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am trying to download and store remote images locally as media, as a part of a Recurring Hosted Service (see [here](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/fundamentals/.../reference/Scheduling/)). I am following the example for Umbraco 9.0 for creating a media item from a stream:

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/management/services/mediaservice/#creating-a-new-media-item-from-a-stream

This is how my method looks:

```
        private void ConvertImageToLocalImage(string remoteImageUrl, string title)
        {

            var downloadFolder = $"{_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath}\\App_Data\\TEMP\\Images";

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(remoteImageUrl.Split('?')[0]);

            var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            var downloadPath = $"{downloadFolder}\\{title.Replace(" ", "_")}{fileExt}";

            if (Directory.Exists(downloadFolder) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadFolder);
            }

            using (var client = new WebClient())

            client.DownloadFile(remoteImageUrl, downloadPath);

            using FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(downloadPath);

            IMedia media = _mediaService.CreateMedia(title, -1, Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image);

            media.SetValue(_mediaFileManager, _shortStringHelper, _contentTypeBaseServiceProvider, _serializer, Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File, fileName, stream);

            _mediaService.Save(media);
        }
```

However, I get the error:

*No overload for method 'SetValue' takes 7 arguments*

The only 'SetValue' method I appear to have access to is:

```
void SetValue(string propertyTypeAlias, object value, string culture = null, string segment = null);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

I have the following using statements at the top of the file:

```
using Umbraco.Cms.Core;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services;
using Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.HostedServices;
```

Comment: What are the using references you have at the top of this file?

Comment: @wingyip I have added the using statements to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out...

I needed to include:

```
using Umbraco.Extensions;
```

And then the signiture for the overloaded method is actually really different to what the docs say, this is the signiture of the method:

```
void SetValue(this IContentBase content, MediaFileManager mediaFileManager, MediaUrlGeneratorCollection mediaUrlGenerators, IShortStringHelper shortStringHelper, IContentTypeBaseServiceProvider contentTypeBaseServiceProvider, string propertyTypeAlias, string filename, Stream filestream, string culture = null, string segment = null)
```

Which ended up looking like this:

```
media.SetValue(_mediaFileManager, _mediaUrlGenerators, _shortStringHelper, _contentTypeBaseServiceProvider, "umbracoFile", fileName, stream)
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm getting this error on Umbraco 11. Here it uses Umbraco. Extensions but it still shows the SetValue method signature as you mentioned first.  Do you have any idea why its happening?